# How to send Mail on Dynamic Mail address through Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have Dynamic Hidden Field Addon And i have added dynamic hidden field in my form as
[dynamichidden recipient-email “types field=’email’ output=’raw'” ]
—>”types field=’email’ output=’raw'” It is a shortcode
and add recipient-email in To: Field
But form is showing 1 configuration error found
Error is present on To: [recipient-email]
(This field has syntax errors)
Pls Help Me

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'cem_wpcf7_posted_data' );

function cem_wpcf7_posted_data( $posted_data ) {

    if(isset($posted_data['to'])){
        switch ($posted_data['to']) {
            case "SALES":
                $posted_data['recipient-email']="testmail@gmail.com";
            break;
            default:
                $posted_data['recipient-email']="test@gmail.com";
    }
}
```

where "recipient-email" is hidden field.

Comment: No i have added mail id on form page with shortcode